# Store as dataset as CSV on disk or each row as an object in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, csv, database-design

I have a dilemma on how to store my data.

Would it make sense to store each row data on my csv file as an object in a mongoDB collection or is it better to store each csv dataset on disk and have each object in mongoDB reference the path to the file on disk?

Comment: Using a database as an alternative filesystem which contains no data itself rather defeats the point of a database, doesn't it?

Comment: @dmfay but what if you're in a scenario where you have to take care of multiple datasets such as kaggle

Comment: So you have multiple datasets. That could map to multiple collections or even multiple databases depending on what exactly they contain. Mongo's perfectly capable of either; the question is whether you need to do anything that a filesystem doesn't cover. If you don't (eg it's _strictly_ csv-in csv-out storage), why even bother with a database?